# Unable to run Pangolin pyexamples on Windows

Tags: python, windows, binding

First let me clarify that I'm a complete newbie with python, so if something is obvious I appologize in advance.

I've followed the steps on the page:

```
git` clone https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin.git
cd Pangolin
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

Alter this, results shows:

```
41 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:11:38.89.
```

When I try to execute the SimpleDisplay.py from my console using python i get.
C:\dev\Pangolin\pyexamples>python SimpleDisplay.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "SimpleDisplay.py", line 4, in
import pypangolin as pango
ImportError: No module named pypangolin

C:\dev\Pangolin\pyexamples>

Analizing the code on the script, i see this.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../build/src')
```

So what's exactly is it trying to locate in this folder?, I do not find anything that is called pypangolin within the ../build/src folder.

Windos 10, Python 2.7.14

Any ideas?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue on Windows when you compile Pangolin on windows the Python Library was not compiled.

If found that on the "yourPath"\Pangolin\src\CMakeLists.txt had exluded windows from the compilation of the Python library, see the **NOT WIN** below

```
option(BUILD_PANGOLIN_PYTHON "Build support for Pangolin Interactive Console" ON)
if(BUILD_PANGOLIN_PYTHON AND BUILD_PANGOLIN_GUI AND BUILD_PANGOLIN_VARS AND NOT WIN)
if(EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../external/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt")
add_subdirectory("../external/pybind11" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external  /pybind11")
set( pybind11_FOUND true)
else()
find_package(pybind11 QUIET)
endif()
```

Once I removed **NOT WIN** clause, I was able to compile the Python library on Windows. then i changed the provided exmaples to point to the correct location where the libray was compiled (Release)

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../build/src/release')
```

for "debug" compile you have to have Python_d.lib and Python_d.dll available.

If you neeed all the details check these links on githud about the resolution.
[Pangolin Issue #426](https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin/issues/426) [Pangolin Issue $425](https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin/issues/425)